# How do I find a fire-rated door that won't dent easily?

Tags: doors

I recently bought [a metal fire-rated door at Lowe's](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Masonite-Right-Hand-Inswing-Primed-Steel-Prehung-Entry-Door-with-Insulating-Core-Common-32-in-x-80-in-Actual-32-in-x-81-625-in/999918646) for the doorway from my house to my garage.  In putting it into my van, it bumped into a dolly cart.  I was surprised to see that it was dented from the bump.  If it is dented so easily in transport, it surely will be dented in ordinary use.  I returned the door.

So how do I find an inexpensive fire-rated door that is more durable, perhaps dent-resistant?  The salespeople seem to think that all metal doors could dent and that all fire doors they might sell are just about the same.

Answer (score 2):

A metal fire rated door is not required.

The door between the garage and house shall be 1) a solid wood door a minimum of 1 3/8” thick, 2) solid or honeycomb core steel door that is not less than 1 3/8” thick, or 3) a 20 minute fire rated door. (See ICC R309.1)

A door is not allowed between the garage and a sleeping room. (See ICC R309.1 openings)

I’d use a solid core wood door with a door frame that has an “intregal door stop” rather than an “applied stop”.

Garages are to be separated from single family residences by 1/2” gypsum board on garage side ONLY, provided the garage does not open into a sleeping room. (See ICC R309.2)

Make sure you confirm all this with the AHJ.

Oh, if you’ve got to have a metal door try Entek.com. Terrible website, but great customer service. Give them a call.